# How to search by a String in API through mySQL database and how to write the url in Postman to test?

Tags: spring-boot, api, postman, crud

I am new to web service. I am trying to create an object with some books information like ISBN, title, author(String) etc. I passed the entered information to mySQL database and I would like to realize 1 function with API to search the books by matching the author's name. My code runs well however I am not sure how should I write the url in postman to test it. I have tried the following ways and none of them working:
http://localhost:8070/book/author/'Simon Armitage'

http://localhost:8070/book/author/"Simon Armitage"

http://localhost:8070/book/author/Simon Armitage

However, it said the book is not found which I have 2 record with this author in mySQL database.

Can anyone let me know what is the problem?

Here is some code I wrote:

```
 //function to get a book with author
public Book getBookByAuthor(String author){
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE author like '%" + author + "%'";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{author}, new BookRowMapper());
    }catch (DatabaseException exception){
        throw new DatabaseException("database error");
    }
}
```

Here is my getMapping code:

```
    //2. Get the book by author 
@GetMapping("/book/author/{author}")
public ResponseEntity<Book> getBookByAuthor(@PathVariable String author) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getBookByAuthor(author), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (BookNotFoundException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

data I have:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "The Dead Sea Poems",
    "author": "Simon Armitage",
    "description": " A collection of poems in which questions of belief and trust, of identity and knowledge, mingle with more mundane considerations, such as the problems of owning a dog, and the vicissitudes of the job market.",
    "publishedDate": "18 September 1995",
    "publisher": "Faber and Faber Ltd",
    "isbn": 5071176003
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "White Egrets",
    "author": "Derek Walcott",
    "description": " In White Egrets, Derek Walcott treats the characteristic subjects of his career--the Caribbean's complex colonial legacy, his love of the Western literary tradition, the wisdom that comes through the passing of time, the always strange joys of new love, and the sometimes terrifying beauty of the natural world--with an intensity and drive that recall his greatest work. Through the mesmerizing repetition of theme and imagery, Walcott creates an almost surflike cadence, broadening the possibilities of rhyme and meter, poetic form and language.",
    "publishedDate": "15 March 2011",
    "publisher": "Farrar, Straus and Giroux",
    "isbn": 9780374532703
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Paper Aeroplane",
    "author": "Simon Armitage",
    "description": " Paper Aeroplane: Poems 1989-2014 is the author's own selection from across a quarter-century of work, from his debut to the latest, uncollected work. Drawing upon all of his award-winning poetry collections, including Kid, Book of Matches, The Universal Home Doctor and Seeing Stars, this generous selection provides an essential gathering of this most thrilling of poets, and is key reading for students and general readers alike.",
    "publishedDate": "18 September 2014",
    "publisher": "Faber and Faber",
    "isbn": 9780571310678
}
```

]

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have a mistake in getByAuthor - you should NEVER directly put user entered parameters into a SQL statement due to the risk of SQL injection. Instead, use parameters, ie SELECT * FROM Book WHERE author like ? .. then ensure you're passing "%" + author + "%" as a parameter (ie new Object[]{"%" + author + "%"})

Comment: Thank you. I've made the changes. I am still wondering how do I generate the url to fetch the information?  I've tried "http://localhost:8070/book/author/Simon" but still doesn't work.